# Html Tag wordpress rest api

Tags: wordpress, laravel, rest, vue.js

I would like to show content of my wordpress rest api however the wordpress html tag doesn't retrieve html.

It turns out like this

```
<p><b>content here blabalbalablabla</b></p> <p><span style="font-weight: 400;">
```

This is my code to call it :

```
<div class="marge" v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id">
<div class="blog-description"><p>{{ post.content.rendered }}</p></div
```

How do I retrieve it with html output not only tag. FYI I'm using vuejs and laravel on this project.

Comment: It looks like you're missing a closing tag for your last div on "your  code"

Comment: It’s very hard to work out what you’re trying to do and what you’re asking. What API are you using? What does the code look like? What are you getting from the API? How does that get into your view? Is this a Blade view we’re looking at or a Vue.js component? How does the data get from Laravel to Vue.js? We need a lot more information to be able to help you. Also, do try and show us as much actual content as you can, rather than just ‘content here’ – it can often reveal the problem itself. Good luck.

Comment: hi guys thank you i'm not missing </div>, it's only example, already try {!!... but it can't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have gather what your are tryin to do is render raw html inside of a vue component. you can do that using `v-html` directive try following

```
<div class="marge" v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id">
  <div class="blog-description">
    <p><span v-html="post.content.rendered"></span></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

for more information read the vue doc on [template syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML)

hope this helps!